# How does one make Spring read from a file to string property?

Tags: spring

I have a bean that has a string property that I would like to set, but I would like it set from a file without changing the bean code.  The bean is something like this.

```
public class SomeBean {
    public void setSomeProperty(String string) { ... }
}
```

I was looking for something like this in the beans.xml file

```
<beans>
   <bean class="SomeBean">
      <property name="someProperty">
         <util:string src="classpath:foo.txt" />
      </property>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` to load a value from a properties file:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PreferencesPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:foo.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        </bean>

<bean class="SomeBean">
       <property name="someProperty" value="${myBean.someProperty}" />
```

Then, in the foo.properties file, you set the property to whatever value you want:

```
myBean.someProperty = value
```

Hope this helps

Comment: no it does not because I would like the file to be kept as is rather than being converted to a properties file.

Comment: @Archimedes Trajano How is your text file formatted ? Does it respect the .properties file format?

Comment: in my case it was a JSON file not a properties file.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way using the Guava classes though it looks really bad.

(The value attribute is all in one line)

```
<property name="someProperty"
  value="#{ T(com.google.common.io.Resources).toString(
              T(com.google.common.io.Resources).getResource('foo.txt'),
              T(java.nio.charset.Charset).forName('UTF-8')) }"/>
```

Hopefully someone can find a better answer.